# Regex for sections of the text that contain a set of words

Tags: regex

I have a large text that has a few paragraphs. I want to search for the text that contains a set of words, not in any order, for example {"word3", "word2", "word1"}. Need to return the section of the text, which can span multiple sentences or paragraphs.
What is the regular expression for this, please?

Comment: Is there anything in your text that signifies that start or the end of a section? Like a special character or even the word 'Section'?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a way to declare how this "section of text" starts and ends.

I will assume that your sections stop at a new line character (`\n`).

Something like:

`(\n?).+(word1|word2|word3).+(\n|\.)`

Could make it work. This will return the whole paragraph (assuming that each paragraph is separated by a `\n` with the next.

Answer (score 0):

lookaheads can be used to ensure multiple conditions, the general form will be

```
(?=.*word1.*$)(?=.*word2.*$)(?=.*word3.*$).*$
```

where `$` could be changed by what is the end of section.

Word boundaries can be used to avoid sub-word matches, also `s` switch may be used if `.` may match newline character.

```
(?=.*\bword1\b.*$)(?=.*\bword2\b.*$)(?=.*\bword3\b.*$).*$
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with mpliax, you must have a way to delimit these sections, a way to define what a paragraph or a sentence is.

Assuming your paragraphs are separated by newlines, and that we're looking for "grep", "contains", and "text", you could use a series of lookaheads to [match that paragraph](https://regex101.com/r/PcC5IW/1/):

```
([^\n]+(?=grep))([^\n]+(?=text))([^\n]+(?=contains))[^\n]+
```

Or this slightly different pattern, which assumes a sentence must end with a period, question mark, or exclamation point (a bad assumption?), and tries to [match just the sentence](https://regex101.com/r/G6n26h/2/):

```
([^\.?!]+(?=grep))([^\.?!]+(?=text))([^\.?!]+(?=contains))[^\.?!]+
```

Both patterns follow this structure: `([NON-delimiter]+(?=keyword))` lookaheads, as many as we want one after the other, so that we know we can "see" our keywords before the next delimiter happens. Then we just match the whole paragraph with the last token `[NON-delimiter]+`.

Answer (score 0):

If you do `ignore the order` of the set of words, I think there are several `combinations` for the set of 3 words, e.g. `abc, acb, bca, bac, cab, cba`.

Thus this seems to be needed to match the possible combinations of the set of 3 words

```
a(bc|cb)|b(ca|ac)|c(ab|ba)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/140),,, in which suppose that `a` means to `word1`, `b` to `word2`, `c` to `word3`.

Of course, for the `words` which essentially accompany `white space`, the `regex` also needs white space, so basically it may be like this,

```
word1 (word2 word3|word3 word2)|word2 (word3 word1|word1 word3)|word3 (word1 word2|word2 word1)
```